# Datagrid tree (two levels) - dynamically generated grids cannot be altered

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, asp.net, datagrid

I am trying to implement a tree view datagrid with two levels.

I am binding my data as follows:

```
private void BindData()
    {
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT dept_code, dept_name FROM Department";
        conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\saher\Documents\TreeTest\TreeDemo\App_Data\TreeData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

        try
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "DepInfo");
            DataGrid1.DataSource = ds;

            DataGrid1.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Response.Write("An Error Has occured!");
            //Response.End();
            Response.Write(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

my ItemDataBound function for my datagrid is as follows:

```
protected void DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        //If your page size is 10, only 10 sub queries will be done.
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            string newSqlQuery = "SELECT S.staff_name FROM Staff as S where S.dep_code ='" + e.Item.Cells[1].Text + "'";
            //Here I am grabbing the additional data and putting it
            //into mini datagrids…
            //If you wish to just use labels, or other controls, just
            //bind the data as you
            //wish, and render to html as I did.

            DataSet ds = this.RunQuery(newSqlQuery);
            DataGrid NewDg = new DataGrid();
            NewDg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            NewDg.Width = Unit.Percentage(100.00);
            DataGridTemplate temp = new DataGridTemplate(ListItemType.Item, "staffCol");
            TemplateColumn tempCol = new TemplateColumn();
            tempCol.ItemTemplate = temp;
            BoundColumn bound = new BoundColumn();
            bound.DataField = "staff_name";
            NewDg.Columns.Add(tempCol);
            NewDg.Columns.Add(bound);
            NewDg.DataSource = ds;
            NewDg.DataBind();
            SetProps(NewDg);

            subGrids.Add(NewDg); // subGrids is a private ArrayList I have to store the grids.



            /**
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            datagrid.RenderControl(htw);
            string DivStart = "<DIV id=’uniquename" + e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString() + "‘ style=’DISPLAY: none;’>";
            string DivBody = sw.ToString();
            string DivEnd = "</DIV>";
            string FullDIV = DivStart + DivBody + DivEnd;
            int LastCellPosition = e.Item.Cells.Count - 1;
            int NewCellPosition = e.Item.Cells.Count - 2;
            e.Item.Cells[0].ID = "CellInfo" + e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString();
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                e.Item.Cells[LastCellPosition].Text = e.Item.Cells[LastCellPosition].Text +
                "</td><tr><td bgcolor=’f5f5f5′></td><td colspan=’" +
                NewCellPosition + "‘>" + FullDIV;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Item.Cells[LastCellPosition].Text = e.Item.Cells[LastCellPosition].Text +
                "</td><tr><td bgcolor=’d3d3d3′></td><td colspan=’" +
                NewCellPosition + "‘>" + FullDIV;
            }
            **/
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            datagrid.RenderControl(htw);
            string DivStart = "<DIV id=\"uniquename" + e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString() + "\" style=\"display:none\";’>";
            string DivBody = sw.ToString();
            string DivEnd = "</DIV>";
            string FullDIV = DivStart + DivBody + DivEnd;
            int LastCellPosition = e.Item.Cells.Count - 1;
            int NewCellPosition = e.Item.Cells.Count - 2;
            e.Item.Cells[0].ID = "CellInfo" + e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString();
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                e.Item.Cells[LastCellPosition].Text = e.Item.Cells[LastCellPosition].Text +
                "</td><tr id =row" + e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString() + "><td bgcolor=’000000′></td><td colspan=’" +
                NewCellPosition + "‘>" + FullDIV;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Item.Cells[LastCellPosition].Text = e.Item.Cells[LastCellPosition].Text +
                "</td><tr id =row" + e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString() + "><td bgcolor=’d3d3d3′></td><td colspan=’" +
                 NewCellPosition + "‘>" + FullDIV;
            }

            //============Set up javascript methods.=============
            e.Item.Cells[0].Attributes["onclick"] = "HideShowPanel('uniquename" +
         e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString() + "'); ChangePlusMinusText('" +
         e.Item.Cells[0].ClientID + "'); SetExpandedDIVInfo('" +
         e.Item.Cells[0].ClientID + "','" + this.txtExpandedDivs.ClientID +
         "', 'uniquename" + e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString() + "');"; 

            e.Item.Cells[0].Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer'";
            e.Item.Cells[0].Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer'";

            Session["checkSession"] = subGrids; // I store the ArrayList in the session so that I won't loose the dataGrids after a post back.                       
        }

    }
```

my original datagrid has a template column with checkboxes and my generated datagrids also have two columns, one for staff name and one is template column with checkboxes. 
The only thing I am stuck on is that I want to check all checkboxes in the NewDg girds I make for every row.

`FindControl(id)` function doesn't work (finds null) for my dataGrids even when I have set unique Id's for the grids.

This is why I populate the girds in a list and store it in the session.

this is my checkedChange event connected to the checkboxes with AutoPostback = true in my DataGrid1 (the parent grid).

```
protected void Check_Change(object s, EventArgs ev)
    {
        ArrayList gridList = (ArrayList)Session["checkSession"];

        foreach (DataGridItem i in DataGrid1.Items)
        {
            string newSqlQuery = "SELECT S.staff_name FROM Staff as S where S.dep_code ='" + i.Cells[1].Text + "'";  

            CheckBox b = (CheckBox)i.Cells[2].Controls[1];

            if (b.Checked)
            {
                DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)gridList[0];

                foreach (DataGridItem item in dg.Items)
                {
                    CheckBox myBox = (CheckBox)item.Cells[0].Controls[0];
                    myBox.Checked = true;
                }
}
}
}
```

This didn't work. I debugged, my List is populated, I have the right number of datagrids but the checkbox isn't altered. What am I missing?? I need to solve this in a way I can get the chosen Items and insert them in my database. I want to know why the dynamically generated dataGrids cannot be altered??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this by simply using a repeater with a datagrid in the item template.

based on either a click on the row in the repeater / a button on the row I would then "toggle" a panels visibility within the template that shows or hides the grid during that postback i would also databind the child grid ... so I only databind the visible grid and not all grids in all rows.

it looked something like this (sorry if its not spot on doing this from head ram):

```
<asp:Repeater ...>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td>
       <asp:Panel ..>
          <asp:GridView ...>
             ...
          </asp:GridView>
       </asp:Panel>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On page load if !IsPostback bind the repeater.
On Row events for items in the repeater rows:
   1. Toggle panel visible for that row
   2. get data
   3. pass to grid within row.
   4. databind grid

to get different views simply use different panels within the item template of the repeater.

seems to work well, and is pretty efficient.

Also: 
I have the child grid in a separate custom control to  keep the code tidy and prevent massive reams of code in 1 code behind file.